# Не работает вложенный transtion Vue v2

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuetify, vue-cli

Transition "modal-content" не срабатывает, вместо неё применяется transition с именем "modal", подскажите пожалуйста как исправить, чтобы к содержимому внутри modal-container применилась своя анимация?

Vue компонент

```
<template>
<transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask" v-if="isModalVisible" @click.self="closeModal">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
            <transition name="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-container" v-if="isModalVisible">
                    <component :is="component"></component>
                </div>
            </transition>
        </div>
    </div>
</transition>
</template>
```

Стили

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.modal-enter {
    &-active {
        animation: modal .3s ease-out;
    }
}

.modal-leave {
    &-active {
        animation: modal .3s ease-out reverse;
    }
}

@keyframes modal {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.modal-content-enter {
    &-active {
        animation: bounce .3s ease-out;
    }
}

.modal-content-leave {
    &-active {
        animation: bounce .3s ease-out reverse;
    }
}

@keyframes bounce {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-350px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `@keyframes modal` дублируется

Comment: @MikalaiParakhnevich исправил, не помогло

Comment: добавил в ответ, вариант рабочего кода с пояснениями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите выполнить анимацию последовательно (предполагаю, что вы пытаетесь этого достичь, используя вложенные `<transition>`), вам следует использовать [Javascript хуки](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#JavaScript-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8) для `<transition>`:

а именно добавить родительскому `<transition>` атрибут:

```
@after-enter="bodyVisible = true"
```

, который запустит анимацию вложенного `<transition>` только после выполнения анимации родительского `<transition>` и для выхода соответственно:

```
@after-leave="$emit('close')"
```

, который запустит анимацию выхода для родительского `<transition>`, после выполнения анимации выхода дочернего `<transition>`

Привожу ваш пример(с внесенными правками):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      modalVisible: false,
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('modal', {
  data: () => {
    return {
      bodyVisible: false,
    }
  },
  template: `
<transition
    name="modal"
    @after-enter="bodyVisible = true"
   >
      <div class="modal-mask" @click="bodyVisible = false">
          <div class="modal-wrapper">
              <transition
                name="modal-content"
                @after-leave="$emit('close')"
              >
                  <div class="modal-container" v-if="bodyVisible"
                @click.stop>
                     Здесь ваш компонент!
                      <button @click="bodyVisible = false">Закрыть модальное окно</button>
                  </div>
              </transition>
          </div>
      </div>
  </transition>
`
})
```

```css
.modal-enter-active {
  animation: modal .3s ease-out;
}

.modal-leave-active {
  animation: modal .3s ease-out reverse;
}

@keyframes modal {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.modal-content-enter-active {
  animation: modal-content .3s ease-out;
}

.modal-content-leave-active {
  animation: modal-content .3s ease-out reverse;
}

@keyframes modal-content {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(350px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  background: #00000080;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-container {
  max-width: 30%;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <modal v-if="modalVisible" @close="modalVisible = false"></modal>
  <button @click="modalVisible=!modalVisible">Открыть модальное окно</button>
</div>
```